# Swipe gesture iphone

Tags: ios4, uigesturerecognizer

I have some trouble to handle swipe on `iPhone`, I create in my interface a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`var:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer;
```

and in my controller : `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Horizontal swipe
    swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                          action:@selector(swipeMethod:)];
    swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; 
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
}
```

And my method to handle swipe is :

```
-(void)swipeMethod: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe!");   
}
```

When I run my code and do a swipe I got nothing? I'm supposed to get : Swipe!

Thanks.

Comment: Do not add it to self, either use self.view (assuming self is a viewcontroller) or use a subview to put the gesture recognizer on. You can put a breakpoint before putting the recognizer and see if its correctly added. See my answer for left&right swipe detection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16810160/936957

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised that doesn't crash with an unrecognized selector error. Try adding the recognizer to your view instead of to your view controller:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer]
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm surprised too, i add it to my view, still nothing!

Answer (score 0):

swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

Does this work?

Don't you have to add two gestureRecognizer for each direction?

Comment: Nope. They can be OR'ed. If you 'Jump to Definition' you'll see this. `typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight = 1 << 0,
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft  = 1 << 1,
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp    = 1 << 2,
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown  = 1 << 3
};`