# how detect swipe gesture direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, gesture-recognition, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i need to detect direction of my swipe gesture and i've got problem with it. gesture is working, but i don't know how to detect direction.
    ...

```
swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectSwipe:)];
[swipeGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
[appView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

-(void)detectSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer { 
switch (recognizer.direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp:
        NSLog(@"smth1");
        break;


    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown:
        NSLog(@"smth2");
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

it's not working :/

Comment: Please define "it's not working." Does the log the incorrect value? Does it not log anything? Is detectSwipe not being called?

Comment: `default` case is called when i swipe to up or to down.

Comment: Since it's just an enum - have you tried to cast and log the value of the recognizer: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `direction` property only defines the *allowed* directions that are recognized as swipes, not the *actual* direction of a particular swipe.

The easiest would be to use two separate gesture recognizers instead. You could also inspect the location of the touch when the gesture starts and when it ends with the `locationInView:` method.

Comment: `CGPoint start = [swipeGesture locationInView:appView];` i use this and this function give me start point of swipe, but how i detect when swipe is ended? only way is to use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible (you're probably better off with two recognizers). Check the `state` of the gesture recognizer in your action. For most gesture recognizers, it transitions from `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, but it could be that the swipe gesture recognizer type doesn't do that, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 51):

Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
    // ...

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    // ...

- (void)didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe{

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Up");
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Down");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need to add 4 gesture recognizer, just add one and in the didSwipe method check the sender's swipe direction, that should do it

Answer (score 18):

Extending omz's solution:

`self.myView` is the view I want to put the gesture recognizer on. The code below is not tested, I guess it would be better to keep the recognizers as `property`s and add them inside `viewDidLoad()` or `xib` file. `self` is a `UIViewController`.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedLeft:)];
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedRight:)];
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Add those two methods to your `UIViewController` and add necessary actions:

```
- (IBAction)swipedRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"swiped right");
}

- (IBAction)swipedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"swiped left");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Swipe Gesture direction detect with Swift 5**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

         let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
         let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))

         leftSwipe.direction = .left
         rightSwipe.direction = .right

         view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
         view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if (sender.direction == .left) {
                print("Swipe Left")
        }

        if (sender.direction == .right) {
            print("Swipe Right")
        }
    }
```