# Detect direction swiped UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

For my own convenience, I have created a single `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` allowing the user to swipe left *and* right invoking the same action in code.
I was wondering whether it is possible to detect the *actual* direction the user swiped inside its action. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8813021/3397217) that discusses just that question already, but maybe something changed with Swift.

Comment: Probably not the answer you were looking for but nothing has changed as of June 16 '17 in terms of being able to detect all swipe directions through a single swipe recognizer from [Apple's API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer). Just create 4 gestures in different direction then link them up to the same selector.

Comment: Hm, such inconvenience, much painful! Ha. I'll leave the question open, in case someone comes around with some awesome solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I mean, if you *__truly truly__* want to you could extend the Swipe Gesture Recognizer. UISwipeGestureRecognizer inherits from [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer) and with that you can get the location and other view properties which you could perform some calculations and try _predicting_ the direction. But you've really got to hate creating four swipe gesture recognizers to do this :)

Comment: Yup, I thought of that too. I was just looking for something that's already been implemented because I often write something myself w/o knowing that it's already pre-built by Apple. I'll probably create a second recognizer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating on @LinusGeffarth this is the best solution I could come up with

```
import UIKit

class SwipeUTIL {
    static func addSwipe(selfVC: UIViewController) {
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: selfVC, action: #selector(selfVC.didSwipe))
        let swipeRight =  UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: selfVC, action: #selector(selfVC.didSwipe))

        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        swipeRight.direction = .right

        selfVC.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
        selfVC.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    }

}

extension UIViewController {
    internal func didSwipe(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer, completion: (@escaping(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) -> Void)) {
        completion(swipe.direction)
    }
}
```

In your View Controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SwipeUTIL.addSwipe(selfVC: self)
    }

    override func didSwipe(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer, completion: @escaping ((_ swipedir: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) -> Void)) {
        print(swipe.direction)
    }
```

Comment: 1) I've created it in code, and it makes no difference whether you set it up using the storyboard, or via code. 2) `.direction` only returns the *allowed* direction(s) the user can swipe, not the direction swiped.

Comment: As stated in my question, I am looking for a way to detect the direction swiped using a single swipe gesture recognizer, rather than creating 4 separate recognizers.

Comment: @Fallah the OP already knows of this answer because its included in the link he's already looked into.